# MySQL Inline Foreign Key doesn't apply restrictions

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables one is a primary table and the other one is child table/foreign key table and I don't have any row in the primary table but still child table accepts row insertion without any restriction... Why it is happening

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS(
   ID   INT              NOT NULL,
   NAME VARCHAR (20)     NOT NULL,
   AGE  INT              NOT NULL,
   ADDRESS  CHAR (25) ,
   SALARY   DECIMAL (18, 2),       
   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ORDERS (
   ID          INT        NOT NULL,
   DATE        DATETIME, 
   CUSTOMER_ID INT references CUSTOMERS(ID),
   AMOUNT     double,
   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

when I insert the data into the child table wihtout inserting into primary tbl, it accepts .. but it shouldn't.. please help

Answer (score 3):

```
CUSTOMER_ID INT references CUSTOMERS(ID)
```

From [the MySQL `CREATE TABLE` documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html) :

> MySQL parses but ignores “inline REFERENCES specifications” (as defined in the SQL standard) where the references are defined as part of the column specification. MySQL accepts `REFERENCES` clauses only when specified as part of a separate `FOREIGN KEY` specification.

You should explictly declare the foreign key, like :

```
CREATE TABLE ORDERS (
   ID          INT NOT NULL,
   DATE        DATETIME, 
   CUSTOMER_ID INT,
   AMOUNT      DOUBLE,
   PRIMARY KEY (ID),
   FOREIGN KEY (CUSTOMER_ID) REFERENCES CUSTOMERS(ID)
);
```

Also, it is generally a good idea to make the referencing column not nullable, as the foreign key by default allows `NULL` values.

```
CREATE TABLE ORDERS (
   ID          INT NOT NULL,
   DATE        DATETIME, 
   CUSTOMER_ID INT NOT NULL,
   AMOUNT      DOUBLE,
   PRIMARY KEY (ID),
   FOREIGN KEY (CUSTOMER_ID) REFERENCES CUSTOMERS(ID)
);
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cUSwDf9EBdPr5sKGr2WtgU/0)**

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the foreign key column "not null" if you don't want to allow null values there.

```
CREATE TABLE ORDERS (
   ID          INT        NOT NULL,
   DATE        DATETIME, 
   CUSTOMER_ID INT NOT NULL references CUSTOMERS(ID),
   AMOUNT     double,
   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```